# Scrapy combine items from multiple processes

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a scrapy script that

1. Finds all '**pages**' nodes in an xml file
2. Parses all those pages, collects data, finds additional pages
3. Additional pages are further parsed and information is collected

Scrapy script:

```
class test_spider(XMLFeedSpider):
 name='test'
 start_urls=['https://www.example.com'] 
 custom_settings={
  'ITEM_PIPELINES':{
   'test.test_pipe': 100,
  },
 }
 itertag='pages'  
 def parse1(self,response,node):
  yield Request('https://www.example.com/'+node.xpath('@id').extract_first()+'/xml-out',callback=self.parse2)
 def parse2(self,response):
  yield{'COLLECT1':response.xpath('/@id').extract_first()} 
  for text in string.split(response.xpath(root+'/node[@id="page"]/text()').extract_first() or '','^'):
   if text is not '':
    yield Request(
     'https://www.example.com/'+text,
     callback=self.parse3,
     dont_filter=True
    )
 def parse3(self,response):
  yield{'COLLECT2':response.xpath('/@id').extract_first()} 
class listings_pipe(object):
 def process_item(self,item,spider):
  pprint(item)
```

Ideal result would be combined dict item such as

> {'COLLECT1':'some data','COLLECT2':['some data','some data',...]}

Is there a way to call pipeline after each parse1 event? and get combined dict of items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Parse2` method, use `meta` and  pass you `collection1` to `parse3` using `meta`. Then in `Parse3` acquire your `collection1`, `extract` your `collection2` and yield combine result as you wish.

For more info on meta you can read [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html)